# My code is showing incorrect mysql syntax although it is correct

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

```
scholar_no = int(input('Enter the Scholar Number'))

mycursor.execute("delete from student1 WHERE Scholar_No = %s", (scholar_no))
mydb1.commit()
```

Comment: To answer this question we need more context. What the exact error. Hows does the structure of the db looks like.. this is too less information for an exact answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a tuple not a single variables, even when it is only a single value

```
mycursor.execute("delete from student1 WHERE Scholar_No = %s", (scholar_no,))
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. You solved the problem! I literally spent the whole day in this!!